# Appium - webdriverio init is not a function

Tags: node.js, appium, webdriver-io, appium-android

I have some code that was generated by Appium Recorder.  When I try to run `node test.js` it says "driver.init is not a function"

I ran `npm install webdriverio` in the same directory and I have the node_modules directory there.

Here is the contents of test.js:

```
// Requires the webdriverio client library
// (npm install webdriverio)
// Then paste this into a .js file and run with Node:
// node <file>.js

const wdio = require('webdriverio');
const caps = {"platformName":"android","platformVersion":"6.0.1","deviceName":"Nexus","automationName":"Appium","browserName":"Chrome"};
const driver = wdio.remote({
  protocol: "http",
  host: "localhost",
  port: 4723,
  path: "/wd/hub",
  desiredCapabilities: caps
});

driver.init()
  .element("com.android.chrome:id/url_bar")
  .setValue("https://www.google.com/")
  .end();
```

I expect the code to run, but it says `TypeError: driver.init is not a function`

Comment: try `npm install webdriverio --save` Is there any other code that uses the library?

Comment: So I tried `rm -rf node_modules` then `npm install webdriverio --save` and then `node tests.js` but I am still getting `driver.init is not a function`.  No other code should use the library

Comment: next time you want to refresh your node_modules folder use `npm ci` added around npm version 5.8

Answer (score 2):

it seems to depend on the version of `webdriverio` you are using. I got the same issue when working with the latest version, but with `"webdriverio": "^4.6.1"`, it works. If you go on the Getting Started section, you'll see the new way to use the module : https://webdriver.io/docs/gettingstarted.html

Hope it helps